# Confusion about whether $\frac{e^{i 2 \pi} - 1}{e^{-i 2 \pi} - 1}$ is undefined or -1

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I'm sure this is a trivial question, so hopefully the response will be quick :)

It seems to me that:
$$
\frac{e^{i 2 \pi} - 1}{e^{-i 2 \pi} - 1} = \frac{1 - 1}{1 - 1} = \frac{0}{0} \Rightarrow Undefined
$$

However, python says this is -1:

```
def coeff(k):
    return (e**(1j * k * 2* pi) - 1) /  (e**(-1j * k * 2 * pi) - 1)

coeff(1)
```

> > %   -1 - 0j

Assuming that python is right leads to a true statement, so Python is not obviously wrong.

$$
\frac{e^{i 2 \pi} - 1}{e^{-i 2 \pi} - 1} = -1 \Rightarrow e^{i 2 \pi}  = 2 - e^{-i 2 \pi} \Rightarrow 1  = 2 - 1 \Rightarrow 1 = 1
$$

However, Python still gives me a divide by zero error when I run coeff(0).

Can you show me the error in my ways that leads me and [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%28i+2+pi%29+-+1%29%2F%28e%5E%28-i+2+pi%29+-+1%29) astray?

Comment: When you multiply both sides by $e^{-i2\pi}-1$, you are multiplying by $0$ !!!

Comment: Absolutely! Now I just have to figure out why Python (mostly) doesn't complain about it.

Comment: I am not very fluent in programming, but the documentation seems to suggest it may be related to the branch cut http://docs.python.org/library/cmath.html

Comment: `>>> e**(1j*2*pi)-1
-2.4492935982947064e-16j
>>> e**(-1j*2*pi)-1
2.4492935982947064e-16j` Python uses double precision, so $e^{2\pi i} \neq 1$ for it.

Comment: It is always import to remember that floating point math (what python does) and real number math (your question) ARE NOT the same thing.  They are similar much of the time, but can give completely different answers in some circumstances that are not uncommon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In python enumerator and denominator are *not* zero, due to rounding errors:

```
e**(-1j*2*pi)-1 -> 2.4492127076447545e-16j
e**(1j*2*pi)-1  -> -2.4492127076447545e-16j
```

For symmetry reasons exactly the same numerical error is made, which then cancels to

```
-1
```